# Android NullPointerException. Почему?

Tags: android, java

Я новый в программировании под андройд, и у меня следущая проблема:
Я использую navigation drawer, при выборе пункта в меню меняю фрагмент. В layout фрагмента, который я подгружаю при клике на пункт меню. у меня есть кнопка и ListView. И вот в классе фрагмента у меня есть такой код:

```
public class InboxFragment extends Fragment{
private ListView ll;
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.inbox_fragment, container, false);
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Button filter_bt;
            // Краш происходит здесь
    filter_bt = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.filter_button);
    filter_bt.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
}

}
```

Код проще некуда, но почему-то мое приложение крашится. Почему это происходит, если кнопка есть? Ошибка - NullPointerException, что-то возвращает ноль. Но, что и почему?

Вот немного ошибок:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.InboxFragment.onCreate(InboxFragment.java:29)
    at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1673)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:872)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1455)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `NullPointerException` возникает, когда вы пытаетесь вызвать метод объекта по неинициализированной ссылке.

Краш на 29 строке в методе `onCreate`.

Если это 

    filter_bt = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.filter_button);

то, вероятно, `getView()` возвращает `null`.

Comment: Как тогда мне "подцепить" кнопку в фрагменте?

Comment: `onCreate` вызывается до `onCreateView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перенесите код из OnCreate в OnViewCreated.

Используйте не getView(), а View, который передается в OnViewCreated.

Fragment должен реализовывать интерфейс OnClickListener. ( implements View.OnClickListener)

```
public class InboxFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
private ListView ll;
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.inbox_fragment, container, false);
}

public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle state)
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, state);
    Button filter_bt;
            // Краш происходит здесь
    filter_bt = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.filter_button);
    filter_bt.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void OnClick(View view)
{
//ЛАЛАЛАЛЛАЛА
}

}
```

Comment: Делаа, всё равно краш

Comment: Можно пример кодом? спасиюо

Comment: сейчас проверю

Comment: Отлично, работает! Но на кнопку не нажимается, оущение буд-то она как перекрыта что ли чем-то

Comment: Статичный фон у кнопки?

Answer (score 2):

onCreate вызывается раньше, чем onCreateView, поэтому у Вас метод getView() возвращает null. Затем Вы у null пытаетесь вызвать findViewById. И получаете NullPointerException. Я рекомендую Вам переписать код вот так:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inbox_fragment, container, false);

Button filter_bt = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.filter_button);
filter_bt.setOnClickListener(this);

return v;
}
```